# Generating a list of continued fractions

Tags: list-manipulation, continued-fractions

Given positive integers $ k $ and $ n $, I would like to generate a list of all the finite continued fractions of length $ k $ in the interval $ [0,1] $ whose partial quotients are bounded above by $ n $.

For instance, when $ k=3 $ and $ n=2 $, the list would be:

$$
\left\{ \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}}, \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}}}, \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1}}}, \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}}, \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}}, \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}}}, \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1}}}, \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}} \right\} = \left\{ \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{5}{7}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{8}, \frac{3}{7}, \frac{5}{12} \right\}.
$$

From [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210864/writing-code-to-produce-continued-fractions), it is easy to produce a function that takes a string of integers and gives the corresponding continued fraction:

```
Contfrac[terms_List] := Fold[1/(#2 + #1) &, Reverse@terms]
```

For instance, evaluating

```
Contfrac[{1,1,1}]
```

returns $ \frac{2}{3} $, as desired.
I'm guessing I can generate the list using this function and $ \texttt{Array} $ somehow, but my naive attempt

```
Array[Contfrac, {2, 2, 2}]
```

for the above example fails.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function "Contfra" needs to be changed to suit your description.

With the changed function you may get all fraction according to k and n by:

```
k = 3;
n = 2;
Contfrac[terms_List] := 
 Fold[1/(#2 + #1) &, 1/Last[terms], Reverse@Most@terms]
Contfrac /@ Tuples[Range[n], {k}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's also this, using the built-in CF function:

```
Block[{k = 3, n = 2},
 FromContinuedFraction /@ 
  PadLeft[Tuples[Range[n], {k}], {Automatic, k + 1}]
 ]
(*  {2/3, 3/5, 3/4, 5/7, 2/5, 3/8, 3/7, 5/12}  *)
```

You need to prepend the integer part 0 with `PadLeft` to get the OP's desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Using [FromContinuedFraction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromContinuedFraction.html):

```
1/(FromContinuedFraction/@Tuples[Range[2], {3}])


     2  3  3  5  2  3  3   5
(* { -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -- } *)
     3  5  4  7  5  8  7  12
```